# Join CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Galera seguinte, tenho uma tabela vaga e outras vaga_cadidato, gostaria de selecionar os dados das mesmas quando o id_entidade for igual no id_entidade. Porém está me mostrando apenas os dados da tabela vaga, gostaria que nesta mesma query mostrasse os dados da vaga_candidato. Segue minha query.

```
function vagaDaEntidade(){
  $status = 'Aguardando Reposta';
  $id_entidade = $this->session->userdata('id_entidade');
  $this->db
  ->select("*")
  ->from("vaga")
  ->join('vaga_candidato', 'vaga.id_vaga = vaga_candidato.id_vaga')
  ->where('status_vaga', $status);


  return $query = $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Abraço a todos.

Comment: Seu banco de dados está com os devidos relacionamentos nas tabelas?

Comment: Quando você faz um `print_r();` na variável da consulta, está retornando o nome das suas colunas da tabela `vaga_candidato`?

Answer (score 1):

Especifique as tabelas no `select`. Tente da seguinte forma que irá funcionar:

```
$this->db
  ->select("vaga.*, vaga_candidato.*")
  ->from("vaga")
  ->join('vaga_candidato', 'vaga.id_vaga = vaga_candidato.id_vaga')
  ->where('status_vaga', $status);
```

Apenas isso!

Comment: Exatamente isso! E se por acaso tenha algum campo com mesmo nome nas duas tabelas utiliza um ALIAS.