# Problemas em um Join CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho o seguinte select :

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_produto_marca');
$this->db->join('tbl_produto', 'tbl_produto_marca.cd_codigo = tbl_produto.cd_marca');
$this->db->where('tbl_produto.cd_codigo', $cd_codigo);
$query = $this->db->get()->row();


foreach ($query as $key) {
    echo $key; //assim está trazendo o cd_codigo e o ds_marca em seguida. 
}
```

Gostaria de mostrar os dados da tbl_produto_marca, que possui duas colunas sendo elas: cd_codigo e ds_marca. Se eu tento

```
echo $key->ds_marca
```

Ocorre o seguinte erro:  Trying to get property of non-object

O que estou fazendo de errado? Meu select? o jeito que eu mostro?

Comment: tenta alterar $this->db->get()->row(); para $this->db->get()->result();

Comment: Acredito que já responderam isso por aqui, [veja](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154516/join-codeigniter?rq=1)

Comment: Você poderia dar um var_dump da variável query para saber o resultado?

Answer (score 0):

Deixe seu código assim:

```
$this->db->join('tbl_produto', 'tbl_produto_marca.cd_codigo = tbl_produto.cd_marca');
$this->db->where('tbl_produto.cd_codigo', $cd_codigo);
$query = $this->db->get('tbl_produto_marca')->result();

foreach ($query as $key) {
    echo $key->cd_codigo . ' ' . $key->ds_marca; //assim está trazendo o cd_codigo e o ds_marca em seguida. 
}
```